# Writing a Twisted Client to send looping GET request to multiple API calls and record response

Tags: python, api, client, twisted

I haven't done twisted programming in a while so I'm trying to get back into it for a new project. I'm attempting to set up a twisted client that can take a list of servers as an argument, and for each server it sends an API GET call and writes the return message to a file.  This API GET call should be repeated every 60 seconds.

I've done it successfully with a single server using Twisted's agent class:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred

import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time

count = 1
filename = "test.csv"

class server_response(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, finished):
        print "init server response"
        self.finished = finished
        self.remaining = 1024 * 10

    def dataReceived(self, bytes):
        if self.remaining:
            display = bytes[:self.remaining]
            print 'Some data received:'
            print display
            with open(filename, "a") as myfile:
                myfile.write(display)

            self.remaining -= len(display)


    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print 'Finished receiving body:', reason.getErrorMessage()

        self.finished.callback(None)

def capture_response(response): 
    print "Capturing response"
    finished = Deferred()
    response.deliverBody(server_response(finished))
    print "Done capturing:", finished

    return finished

def responseFail(err):
    print "error" + err
    reactor.stop()


def cl(ignored):
    print "sending req"
    agent = Agent(reactor)
    headers = {
    'authorization': [<snipped>],
    'cache-control': [<snipped>],
    'postman-token': [<snipped>]
    }

    URL = <snipped>
    print URL

    a = agent.request(
        'GET',
        URL,
        Headers(headers),
        None)

    a.addCallback(capture_response)
    reactor.callLater(60, cl, None)
    #a.addBoth(cbShutdown, count)


def cbShutdown(ignored, count):
    print "reactor stop"
    reactor.stop()

def parse_args():
    usage = """usage: %prog [options] [hostname]:port ...
    Run it like this:
      python test.py hostname1:instanceName1 hostname2:instancename2 ...
    """

    parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage)

    _, addresses = parser.parse_args()

    if not addresses:
        print parser.format_help()
        parser.exit()

    def parse_address(addr):
        if ':' not in addr:
            hostName = '127.0.0.1'
            instanceName = addr
        else:
            hostName, instanceName = addr.split(':', 1)

        return hostName, instanceName

    return map(parse_address, addresses)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = Deferred()
    d.addCallbacks(cl, responseFail)
    reactor.callWhenRunning(d.callback, None)

    reactor.run()
```

However I'm having a tough time figuring out how to have multiple agents sending calls. With this, I'm relying on the end of the write in cl() ---reactor.callLater(60, cl, None) to create the call loop. **So how do I create multiple call agent protocols (server_response(Protocol)) and continue to loop through the GET for each of them once my reactor is started?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look what the cat dragged in!

> So how do I create multiple call agent

Use [`treq`](http://treq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). You rarely want to get tangled up with the `Agent` class.

> This API GET call should be repeated every 60 seconds

Use [`LoopingCalls`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/time.html) instead of `callLater`, in this case it's easier and you'll run into less problems later.

```
import treq
from twisted.internet import task, reactor

filename = 'test.csv'

def writeToFile(content):
    with open(filename, 'ab') as f:
        f.write(content)

def everyMinute(*urls):
    for url in urls:
        d = treq.get(url)
        d.addCallback(treq.content)
        d.addCallback(writeToFile)

#----- Main -----#            
sites = [
    'https://www.google.com',
    'https://www.amazon.com',
    'https://www.facebook.com']

repeating = task.LoopingCall(everyMinute, *sites)
repeating.start(60)

reactor.run()
```

It starts in the `everyMinute()` function, which runs every 60 seconds.  Within that function, each endpoint is queried and once the contents of the response becomes available, the `treq.content` function takes the response and returns the contents. Finally the contents are written to a file.

PS

Are you scraping or trying to extract something from those sites?  If you are [`scrapy`](http://scrapy.org/) might be a good option for you.

Comment: Thanks @notorious.no you rebel scum you