# Class for making asynchronous API requests with Twisted

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted

I am working on development of a system that collect data from rest servers and manipulates it.

One of the requirements is multiple and frequent API requests. We currently implement this in a somewhat synchronous way. I can easily implement this using threads but considering the system might need to support thousands of requests per second I think it would be wise to utilize Twisted's ability to efficiently implement the above. I have seen [this blog post](http://oubiwann.blogspot.co.il/2008/06/async-batching-with-twisted-walkthrough.html) and the whole idea of deferred list seems to do the trick. But I am kind of stuck with how to structure my class (can't wrap my mind around how Twisted works).

Can you try to outline the structure of the class that will run the event-loop and will be able to get a list of URLs and headers and return a list of results after making the requests asynchronously?

Do you know of a better way of implementing this in python?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://tavendo.com/blog/post/going-asynchronous-from-flask-to-twisted-klein/)?

Comment: Too vague as it stands to sketch out an outline. Please could you provide more detail as to objective?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to use a Twisted project called [`treq`](http://treq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which allows you to send requests to HTTP endpoints. It works alot like [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).  I recently helped a friend [here in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133507/writing-a-twisted-client-to-send-looping-get-request-to-multiple-api-calls-and-r/39136513#39136513).  My answer there might be of some use to you.  If you still need more help, just make a comment and I'll try my best to update this answer.